# While toggle a div alignment changes for other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a responsive templete. This issue came while testing on mobile device. So if you want to reproduce this 
issue, then please use a small screen device or zoom in your PC browser.
**Problem description:**
Check the screen shot below.

[image]

While clicking on the  "<<<" button, the right side bar is comming out. But my main content is getting displaced, which I don't want.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #F5FFF2;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.left-side-bar {
    width:220px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 220px;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right-side-bar {
    width:320px;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    opacity:0.4;
    display:block;
}
.right-responsive-button {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:black;
    float: right;
    display:none;
    color: white;
}
.content-detail1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 330px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}
.content-detail-header {
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C7D1DD;
    text-align:right;
}
.content-detail-header span {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.footer {
    height:80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index=10;
}
/*responsive elements*/
.responsive-top-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #043d01);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000, #043d01);
    /*For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000, #043d01);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15*/
    background: linear-gradient(#000000, #043d01);
    /* Standard syntax */
    display:none;
}
.topbar-button {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.001);
}
.topbar-button:active {
    background:#093E01;
}
.topbar-button-bar {
    width: 40px;
    height:5px;
    margin-top:4px;
    background:white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.responsive-menu {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    background: rgba(5, 34, 0, 0.4);
    display: none;
}
.responsive-menu-item {
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
.responsive-menu-item a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family:"calibri", serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#062A00;
}
.responsive-menu-item a:hover {
    color:blue;
}
/*property while small screen*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .left-side-bar {
        display:none;
    }
    .content {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .content-detail1 {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .responsive-top-bar {
        display:block;
    }
    .topbar-button {
        display:block;
    }
    .right-side-bar {
        display:none;
    }
    .right-responsive-button {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="left-side-bar">asdasd</div>
    <div class="content">
        <!--Responsive design start-->
        <div class="responsive-top-bar">
            <button type="button" class="topbar-button" onclick="showoptions()">
                <div class="topbar-button-bar"></div>
                <div class="topbar-button-bar"></div>
                <div class="topbar-button-bar"></div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive-menu">
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">asddddddd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">asddddddddddd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">sadddddddddddd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">zxccccccccccccc</a>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">sddddddddddddd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">cvcccccccccccc</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Responsive design end-->
        <!--main content start-->
        <div class="right-side-bar"></div>
        <div class="right-responsive-button">
            <<<
        </div>
        <div class="content-detail1">
            <div class="content-detail-header">
                <span>Tracks of the week</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--main content end-->
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

```js
function showoptions() {
    $(".responsive-menu").slideToggle(200);
};
$(".right-responsive-button").click(function(){
    $(".right-side-bar").animate({ width: 'toggle' });
})
```

Please help.

Comment: To keep the content at its place, you have to give position fixed on the right side bar. This will not make your content move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your "right bar" absolute so once out of the html flow it won't mess with any of your content. Then position the bar outside the window which is easy as the width is set. Basically:

```
    .right-side-bar{
        width:320px;
        height: 100%;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        opacity:0.4;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        right:-320px;            
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        }
```

Then remove the `display:none`from your queries. Finally I would use css transition insteed of jquery animation. Just add a class to your bar when click the buttom like this:

```
$(".right-responsive-button").click(function(){
    $(".right-side-bar").toggleClass('show');
})
```

and this css:

```
    .show {
        right:0;
    }
```

and give your buttom a positive z-index so you can turn the menu off (if not it will be place under your menu when it's visible.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/07dmh3gL/)**

Edited: or even better, insteed of a transition from `right:320px` to `right:0` You could make it from `width:0` to `width:320px. This way you won't have any horizontal scroll bar messing around.

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07dmh3gL/2/)**

Comment: The right:-320px;  property is messing the design while in normal size window.

Comment: Its a good approach. But my right shde bar should not be hidden in normal screen. If I set width:0 this right side bar is not displaying while opend from normal pc.

Comment: Nothing easier. Just keep  the `width: 320px`  in the class and set it to 0 in the mediaqueris (where you want the bar to not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0adf0037/

**Modified CSS**

```
.right-side-bar {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    right:0
}
.right-responsive-button {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    right:0;
}
.content-detail1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
```

**Modified JS**

```
$(".right-responsive-button").click(function () {
    $(".right-side-bar").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $(this).animate({
        "right": "320px"
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but I dont want the position of right-side-bar to be fixed.

Comment: @Arijit: any specific reason behind this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawat/fer2vmkp/)

**Modified JS**

```
function showoptions() {
    $( ".responsive-menu" ).slideToggle(200);
};
$(".right-responsive-button").click(function(){
    $(".right-side-bar").animate({width:'toggle'});
    $("body").toggleClass("slide-open");
})
```

**Add CSS:**

```
.responsive-top-bar,
.responsive-menu,
.content-detail1,
.footer{
          transition:all .5s;
 }
 .slide-open .responsive-top-bar,
 .slide-open .responsive-menu,
 .slide-open .content-detail1,
 .slide-open .footer{     
      transform:translate3d(-320px, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 }
```